# Redshift returns a []uint8 instead of an integer, converting between them returns incorrect values

Tags: go, amazon-redshift

I have a service which takes a SQL Query, runs the query on Amazon Redshift, using the database/sql drivers. However, I can't convert the result to a struct, because the queries are big data tasks on various tables, not created within this service. So I have to return a 'loose' data structure. I'm parsing the data returned into JSON and storing it in S3.

However, I'm having some odd issues with the data types returned. The queries, for numeric columns, return a map of uint8's instead of a numeric value. I understand that this is because the database driver can't have an opinion on what to convert it to because it could be imprecise. But I can't seem to be able to convert between []uint8 and an integer either.

Here's my code that queries the database:

```
// Execute executes SQL commands
func (r *Runner) Execute(query string, args ...interface{}) (types.Results, error) {
    var results types.Results
    rows, err := r.db.Query(query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }

    columns, _ := rows.Columns()
    colNum := len(columns)

    values := make([]interface{}, colNum)
    for i := range values {
        var ii interface{}
        values[i] = &ii
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(values...)
        result := make(types.Result)
        for i, colName := range columns {
            rawValue := *(values[i].(*interface{}))
            if reflect.TypeOf(rawValue).String() == "[]uint8" {
                byteVal := rawValue.([]byte)
                val := Intfrombytes(byteVal)
                log.Println("Converted:", val)
            }
            result[colName] = rawValue
        }
        results = append(results, result)
    }
    return results, nil
}
```

I created the following function to attempt to convert between `[]uint8` and `uint32`.

```
func Intfrombytes(bytes []uint8) uint16 {
    bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(bytes)
    return bits
}
```

However, if I insert `200` into that table, I get back `12339`. The approach feels pretty flaky, generally. I'm doubting my decision to use Go for this as I'm dealing with undefined, loose data structures.

Is there a better approach to generic queries such as my example, or is there a way I can convert my numeric results into an integer?

Comment: Postgres tables have a strictly-defined schema, why can't you map your colums to well-defined types?

Comment: @Adrian because this service powers a web based SQL editor, which takes lots of SQL queries and returns JSON data. It's used for loads of different tables. Currently numbers are being converted to []uint8, which `json.Marshal` converts into base64 strings. So in the results, all numbers come back as base64! 

It's not a typical service which is modelled and has structs, it's doing generic database jobs and returning results pretty much.

Comment: Have you tried bigendian? At least it seems like that's what `lib/pq` is using. https://github.com/lib/pq/search?q=endian&unscoped_q=endian

Comment: @mkopriva BigEndian 16 gives me an integer back that's completely wrong, BigEndian 32 throw an out of range error

Comment: I think you might be interpreting a string ([]uint8 == []byte), actually. See https://play.golang.org/p/Rfpey2NPiI7

Comment: @EwanValentine I see, by "numeric columns" do you mean the arbitrary precision type `numeric`? Or an `integer` type, or `real`?

Comment: @MarkR. that's absolutely correct, all I needed to do is convert it into string and I got the correct value, thank you so much, great spot! Post that as a separate comment and I'll accept that as the answer. Thanks to everyone else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be interpreting a string ([]uint8 == []byte), actually. See https://play.golang.org/p/Rfpey2NPiI7

```
originalValue := []uint8{0x32, 0x30, 0x30} // "200"
bValue := []byte(originalValue) // byte is a uint8 anyway
fmt.Printf("Converted to uint16: %d\n", binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(bValue))
fmt.Printf("Actual value: %s", string(bValue))
```

This has bitten me before when dealing with `pq` and some crypto code.

Comment: Answers are required to be complete, without following links. For this reason, I have copied the substance of your answer's code into the answer directly, to avoid your answer being deleted.